# How to model this type of edges in chocolate's packshots

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, sculpting, displacement

I need to model this inside of a chocolate usually seen in packshots. I started with block modelling then started sculpting it. I easily sculpted the liquid chocolate in between wafers. But was not able to find any ideas on how to sculpt that thickness part of the chocolate on the inside and the wafers too. I tried using displacement maps too but couldn't figure out how to proceed to get this look. Any idea how can i achieve this type of look?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start is procedural modeling using modifiers:

1. Add a Cube

[image]

2. Add a second Cube and Bevel the side edges. Delete the Front and Back faces and add a Solidify modifier to it. Make sure the faces of the resulting mesh do not self-intersect. Optionally You can throw a Subdivision Modifier with Level 1-2 for smoothness.

[image]

3. Align the two objects so they overlap

[image]

4. Subdivide the first cube using Subdivision Surface Modifier and add a second one if needed. Do not go too high on subdiv. levels!

[image]

5. Add a Displace Modifier with Coordinates Object and add an Empty to control the displacement. The settings are as follows:

[image]

6 The Texture settings look like this:

[image]

7. Add a Boolean Modifier with Intersect option and choose the Second Cube:

[image]

Now You can apply all Modifiers. Remesh the whole object with high resolution and sculpt more details.

**Advanced tip**:

If you have the chocolate bar already modeled you can use it with the displaced "Voronoi" cube to Intersect Boolean the sides and then a second Intersect Boolean with the Solidified object for a finished chocolate layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rumen. It was a ton of help. 

Answer (score 3):

You could first sculpt (even more than I did if you have the patience):

[image]

Then give it a material with a mix of several *Voronoi Texture* in order to mix different size of holes, plug into a *Bump* node, a *Noise Texture* as *Base Color*:

[image]

As for the solid chocolate part, maybe sculpt as well?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will follow this approach. Can you please also give me a tip on how to achieve that broken part of chocolate effect on its depth ?

Comment: I've edited, I would simply sculpt it

Comment: Thanks a lot 